# Estimate block size and constant from image for adaptive threshold cv2 python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, adaptive-threshold

I'm using

```
import cv2
cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, 
                                    cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,
                                    11,
                                    0)
```

in python to compute a preprocess on different types of images. Since a constant C (0 in this case) and the kernel size (11 in this case) can be good for a specific type of image and bad for another type, is there a way to calculate them dynamically using some features of an image?

Comment: The block size depends on the size of the features that you want to isolate. This raises two difficulties: 1) no algorithm can guess which features you are after, 2) finding the size of the features present requires segmentation methods harder than adaptive thresholding.

Comment: Just one thing is granted: a constant value 0 is usually a very poor choice.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, what you can do for a specific case is to collect a representative sample of images, adjust the constants by hand for each, and keep the values that work best. Also question the "why" you need adaptive thresholding.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I tried with Otsu, but for some images I lost some parte of the text

Comment: Is the character size fixed ?

Comment: no, depends on the image type

Comment: @YvesDaoust also, is better to use cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV or cv2.THRESH_BINARY ? for pytesseract?

Comment: There is no universal solution.